# How do I specify an example value for a list of strings, for Swashbuckle to generate for OpenAPI?

Tags: .net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I'm annotating all of my model objects with documentation comments so that Swashbuckle can show useful values in the example response it generates for each of my methods. It works great for integers, strings, enumerations, and lists of other model objects that have similar documentation applied:

```cs
public class MyModel {
    /// <example>1234</example>
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    /// <example>Jason Sadler</example>
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // etc...
}
```

However I can't figure out how to provide an example value for a *list* of strings. For instance the following doesn't produce the result I'd like:

```cs
public class AnotherModel {
        /// <example>18005555555</example>
        [JsonProperty("phoneNumbers")]
        public IEnumerable<string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
        /// <example>["18005555555"]</example>
        [JsonProperty("otherNumbers")]
        public IEnumerable<string> OtherNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

For this model I get:

```
{
    "phoneNumbers": "18005555555",
    "otherNumbers": "[\"18005555555\"]"
}
```

What I *want* to generate is:

```
{
    "phoneNumbers": [
        "18005555555"
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to do this with Swashbuckle right now, or should I file a feature request? Thanks!

Comment: I just run into the same issueI

Answer (score 2):

The quotes must be escaped using `&quot;`

```
/// <example>[&quot;18005555555&quot;]</example>
[JsonProperty("otherNumbers")]
public IEnumerable<string> OtherNumbers { get; set; }
```